# Animation in imageview in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

i have four imageviews in a linear layout in such a manner that only three are shown at a time.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

 <translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="-33%" 
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true" />

</set>
```

i m using this animation to move them from right to left. i have applied this animation to all the images in onFling method. but the problem is that they move to left side but immediately come back to its original position. 
i want them to stay on their new positions.
and on swiping first time the first image should move out of the screen and fourth image should move in from right side of screen.
can anyone tell me how can i do this.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-33%" />

</set>
```

You need to add `fillAfter=true` attributes to set.

And most important thing why you embedding translate animation inside set?

`Set` is used when you want mixture of multiple kind of animations.

Comment: thanks images are not coming back to their original positions..:) but the fourth image is not coming in..how to do that..?? thanks